# Unable to start Gogo shell getting connect failed error

Tags: telnet, liferay-7, liferay-dxp, gogo-shell

I am new to liferay and while trying to open gogo shell through cmd using this command "telnet localhost 11311" i am getting this error,
ERROR: "Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 11311: Connect failed"

I have tried changing port number in portal-developer.properties but no success.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my above problem.

Problem No. 1: Unable to start Gogo Shell

Solution: Steps that I tried,
To enable Developer Mode for your server in Dev Studio CE, follow these steps:

•   Double-click on your server in the Servers window and open the Liferay Launch section.
•   Select Custom Launch Settings and check the Use developer mode option.
•   Save the changes and start your server.

After enabling developers mode I tried this,
And if you look at portal-developer.properties, the key configuration line (that you could just add to your portal-ext.properties file) is

module.framework.properties.osgi.console=localhost:11311

Comment: Please do _never_ post text as images - because the text in images can neither be indexed nor copied. And you should embed even other images (as shown in my edit above) and not just link them.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke thanks for your feedback will keep in mind in future.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for Liferay 7.1 (https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-1/breaking-changes)

> Disabled Access to Gogo Shell Using Telnet Date: 2018-Jun-25 
>   JIRA Ticket: LPS-82849 What changed? The ability to access and interact
>   with Liferay Portal’s OSGi framework using the Gogo shell via your
>   system’s telnet client has been disabled.
>
> Who is affected? This affects anyone who used their system’s telnet
>   client to access the Gogo shell, or leveraged the Gogo shell in
>   external plugins/tooling using the telnet client.
>
> How should I update my code? Liferay Portal now offers the Gogo Shell
>   portlet, which you can access in the Control Panel → Configuration →
>   Gogo Shell.
>
> If you prefer using your telnet client to access the Gogo shell, you
>   must enable Developer Mode. You can do this by creating a
>   portal-ext.properties file in your Liferay home folder and adding the
>   following property:
>
> include-and-override=portal-developer.properties Developer Mode is
>   enabled upon starting your app server.

Simply use the protlet or enable the dev mode